# <identifier> expected on line 8

Tags: java

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class string4 extends Applet implements TextListener{
Label lblMessage;
TextField txtText1;
String strString1="";
Font fntFont=new Font("Georgia",Font.Bold,20);
public void init(){
lblMessage=new Label("enter some words");
add(lblMessage);
txtText1=new TextField(20);
add(txtText1);
txtText1.addTextListener(this);
}
public void paint(Graphics objG){
objG.setFont(fntFont);
objG.drawString="strString 1,202,62";
}
public void textValueChanged(TextEvent objE){
strString1=txtText1.getText();
}
}
```

this the edited one,,I tried it but still have an error
this is what the cmd says
C:\sample java>javac string4.java
string4.java:8: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable Bold
location: class java.awt.Font
Font fntFont=new Font("Georgia",Font.Bold,20);

string4.java:18: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable drawString
location: class java.awt.Graphics
objG.drawString="strString 1,202,62";

2 errors

Comment: Well, which is line 8?  Does it look correct?

Comment: Your problem is `objG.drawString="strString 1,202,62"` and a lot of other problems, pointed out in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to write

```
Font fntFont=new Font("Georgia",Font.Bold,20);
```

you are writing

```
fntFont=new Font("Georgia",Font.Bold,20);
```

where there is no `type definition`.

And you need to `import` that on top too.

If I'm not wrong you are not using IDE. If so,I'm suggesting you to use a IDE,which will help you to get rid doff of all these type of `compile` time errors,I'm sure that saves you lot of time.

Comment: I'd tried it and the command prompt tellsC:\sample java>javac string4.java
string4.java:8: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable Bold
location: class java.awt.Font
Font fntFont=new Font("Georgia",Font.Bold,20);
                                    ^
string4.java:18: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable drawString
location: class java.awt.Graphics
objG.drawString="strString 1,202,62";
    ^
2 errors

Answer (score 2):

You are missing to define the type for

```
fntFont
```

Java is a strongly typed language and hence you need to define the type of all the variables.

Replace this :

```
fntFont=new Font("Georgia",Font.Bold,20);
```

with

```
Font fntFont=new Font("Georgia",Font.Bold,20);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fntFont=new Font("Georgia",Font.Bold,20);// You have to define the type
```

In java When we are creating a object we have to do as follows

```
Type(Class Name) name_for_object=new Type(input argument here if accept by constructor);
```

Use

```
Font fntFont=new Font("Georgia",Font.Bold,20);
```